# Where is a Python built-in object's __enter__() and __exit__() defined?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager, code-inspection

I've read that the object's __ enter__() and __ exit__() methods are called every time 'with' is used. I understand that for user-defined objects, you can define those methods yourself, but I don't understand how this works for built-in objects/functions like 'open' or even the testcases.

This code works as expected and I assume it closes the file with __ exit__():

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hi there!')
```

or

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    remove_driver(self.driver)  # self refers to a class that inherits from the default unittest.TestCase
```

Yet, there's no such __ enter__() or __ exit__() method on either object when I inspect it:

[image]

[image]

So how is 'open' working with 'with'? Shouldn't objects that support context management protocol have __ enter__() and __ exit__() methods defined and inspectable?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots to share text.

Comment: Try `'__exit__' in dir(open('/dev/null'))`

Comment: `open` is not the object that supports the context manager protocol.  Its *return value* is the object that supports that protocol.  Likewise for `assertRaises`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`open()` is a function.  It *returns* something that has an `__enter__` and `__exit__` method.  Look at something like this:

```
>>> class f:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print 'init'
...     def __enter__(self):
...         print 'enter'
...     def __exit__(self, *a):
...         print 'exit'
... 
>>> with f():
...     pass
... 
init
enter
exit
>>> def return_f():
...     return f()
... 
>>> with return_f():
...     pass
... 
init
enter
exit
```

Of course, `return_f` itself does not have those methods, but what it returns does.

Answer (score 5):

`open` is a function that returns a file object with the context methods, and `self.assertRaises` is a method that returns an object with the context methods, try checking the `dir` of their return value:

```
>>> x = open(__file__, "r")
>>> x
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.py' mode='r' encoding='US-ASCII'>
>>> type(x)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
>>> "__exit__" in dir(x)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking whether the `open` function itself or the `assertRaises` method itself has `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, when you should be looking at what methods the return value has.