# How to write a function that can be called and used as context manager?

Tags: python, contextmanager

The builtin `open()` can be used as function or as context manager.

```
f = open(filename)
f.read()

with open(filename) as f:
    f.read()
```

I would like to write my own function, that can also be used in both ways. For simplicity of the example, let's say I want to implement a function `myopen()`.

### What doesn't work:

#### A simple context-decorated function:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def myopen(filename):
    try:
       f = open(filename)
       yield f
    finally:
       f.close()

>>> myopen(somefile)
<contextlib.GeneratorContextManager at 0x2b6bf7727610>
```

it returns a `GeneratorContextManager` instead of a file object.

#### A context class:

```
class myopen(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.file = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.file = open(filename)
        return self.file

    def __exit__(self):
        self.file.close()

    def __call__(filename):
        return open(filename)

>>> myopen(somefile)
__main__.myopen
```

Calling the class obviously creates an instance as it should. I would have to create an instance and call it (`f = myopen(somefile)()`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is a Python built-in object's \_\_enter\_\_() and \_\_exit\_\_() defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666733/where-is-a-python-built-in-objects-enter-and-exit-defined)